# turbolinks doesn't change redirect url when unauthenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When turbolinks off, like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

An unauthenticated user tries to visit url, for example `/themes/new`, which is protected by authenticate_user! of devise gem.
Then he would normally be redirected to `/sign_in`.

But when turbolinks on, like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

If an user tries to visit `/themes/new`, he sees the same screen as `/sign_in`. But the url is `/themes/new`.

Why does this change happen?

I read code to figure it out using pry-byebug. But it's too complicated for me.

Rails 4.2.0
devise 3.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/22), and somewhat a limitation of the goal.

You can [adjust the url manually](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#triggering-a-turbolinks-visit-manually), but in this case that would potentially require a lot of overriding gem methods to use the appropriate option. It will also force a "real" redirect, which will be slower.

I think a better solution would be to reimagine your login UI to not require a redirect to a separate page at all. Perhaps it could open the dialog in a modal window, be part of the main navigation, drop down from the main navigation in a stylized container, etc. This will give you a little extra visual panache, while avoiding this issue altogether.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I understand the cause of the problem thanks to you. This is a limitation of turbolinks. So I decide not to use turbolinks.